# Launch android app automatically from web link without popup options while can redirect to download page if app is not installed

Tags: android, intentfilter, url-scheme, uri-scheme

I have found a way to do it using the custom URI scheme with intent-filter. But it has a problem when myapp is not installed.

If I use the http scheme like following, it can redirect user to the download page when the app is not installed; but if myapp is already installed, it will popup the option window asking user to choose open with browser or myapp. Here I want it can directly launch myapp without asking.

How can I take advantage of both http scheme and the custom scheme?

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="XXX" android:path="YYY"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Thank you.

Comment: where is that web link? In a WebView inside the app ? You can try to do it by code. You need to check whether the app is installed or not.

Comment: Web link is in the browser (e.g. Android Browser). I think there is no way to check whether an app is installed or not in the browser...

Comment: When your app is not installed, where are you adding that scheme ?

Comment: When the app is not installed, no scheme added. The web link cannot be caught by the app and will be opened in the browser like a normal url. The problem is when the app is installed, the web link can be caught by both browser and app, it will ask user to choose to open with which one.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. You can do nothing. You can't change the behavior of any app that's not yours. The browser will always give the user to choose from the list of App that can open that scheme.